# What is the default window type for rolling windows in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, statistics

I am trying to replicate some calculations in java which were done using pandas and python. I am having trouble with the function `Rolling().quantile()`.

Does anybody know of the window type that is used when one is not explicitly set?

Thank you

Comment: No window type is used?

Comment: The function is given by `DataFrame.rolling(window, min_periods=None, freq=None, center=False, win_type=None, on=None, axis=0, closed=None)` so if `win_type` is not set.

Comment: `win_type` would mean some sort of interpolation of the data, am I correct? If there is no type specified, no interpolation is done. The function is applied on the rolling groups as is.

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct. In which case I am still confused as to how the quantile is then calculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came across the question in which the explicit calculation of the quantiles is explained.

[Python Pandas - Quantile calculation manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887383/python-pandas-quantile-calculation-manually)